# DBeaver Code Completion has no proposals for even basic SLQ commands

Tags: dbeaver

I just started using DBeaver and something seems very wrong with code completion.

I was expecting to be able to type part of a command (like SEL) and hit TAB or something like that and it would complete the command for me. But nothing is happening for me and even if I use the "Activate SQL Assist" shortcut (^Space) it shows a list but it only contains "no proposals". Seems like maybe I'm missing a database of commands or something?

Note that if I finish the entire command in lower case and then hit TAB it will convert to upper case, so that part is working fine.

[no proposals!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2iSD.png)

[code completion preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfH3M.png)